# Cannot mix JPA positional parameters and native Hibernate positional/ordinal parameters

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using Hibernate/JPA to execute native PostGIS queries. The problem with these queries is that they need parameters that are not of the classical X = 'value' form.

My query is :-

```
@Modifying
@Query(value="UPDATE memo SET readMemo = true and updatedBy_id = ?1 and updatedBy = ?1 and updatedOn = ?2 where assignToUser_id = 1? and readMemo = false and deleted = false ",nativeQuery = true)
void readAllMenoByCurrentUser(Long id, Date updateTime);
```

Error :-

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Cannot mix JPA positional parameters and native Hibernate positional/ordinal parameters; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot mix JPA positional parameters and native Hibernate positional/ordinal parameters
```

Does anyone know how to solve in this case ?

Answer (score 5):

You have `"1?"` in your query. This will mean it tries to interpret that as a "?" (SQL parameter) rather than positional parameter. Change it to `"?1"`